# PHP array_push() returns numeric keys too instead only string keys

Tags: php, array-push

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL. Because I am still learning PHP and MySQLi, I do not completely understand why this code prints double results with numeric keys too. I need push only string keys with values. Thanks for some direction.

**code**

```
if ( $r = $mysqli -> query ( $q ) ) {
    ${ 'err_css_' . $err_asid } = array ();
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r ) ) {
        array_push ( ${ 'err_css_' . $err_asid }, ${ 'err_css_' . $err_asid }[$row['language_asid']]=$row['value'] );

    }
    print_r ( ${'err_css_' . $err_asid } );
}
```

**result:**

```
Array (
  [ces] => background:czech_flag_url;
  [0] => background:czech_flag_url; // i dont want numeric key
  [eng] => background:english_flag_url;
  [1] => background:english_flag_url; // i dont want numeric key
)
```

Comment: `fetch_array` populates both numeric and string keys, you're looking for `fetch_assoc`.

Comment: @georg If I change it to `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $r ) )`, the result is same.

Comment: `why this code prints double results with numeric keys too` this is by default, otherwise you need to pass additional flags in `fetch_array` for what you really want.

Comment: Yes, right, the problem is with array_push, not fetch_array. Remove array_push, and simply write `$array[$row['language_asid']] = $row['value']`

Comment: @georg Thank you very much :) That was my target, make the answer if you want. I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `array_push` incorrectly. Actually, you don't need it at all:

```
if ( $r = $mysqli->query ( $q ) ) {
    $css = array ();
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r ) ) {
        $css[$row['language_asid']] = $row['value'] );
    }
}
```

Also, I'd suggest that you don't use "variable variables". This is an essentially useless feature, that does nothing but reduce readability of your code. Use arrays or objects:

```
${ 'err_css_' . $err_asid } = array (); // NO

$err_css[$err_asid] = array ();         // yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mysqli_fetch_array`
You need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is showing double results is because there is double results! mysqli_fetch_array() produces both associative and numerical arrays with identical values. Consider either using mysqli_fetch_assoc() or using is_numeric($key) to filter the results further.